# How do I find all the methods that have specific parameters with reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, methods, signature

I need to find all the methods in a class that accept a set of parameters in a specific order, some of them are generics (Collection).
The example on the Sun web site only works with non generic classes:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html

cheers in advance

Answer (score 2):

[Method.getGenericParameterTypes](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericParameterTypes()) is the method for you!

*<insert usual comment about reflection almost certainly being a bad idea here>*